# Jetty Server not Working for War with JSPs

Tags: jetty, war

I am trying to create a simple jetty server/container that will take a war file and deploy. This is not embedded jetty with spring-boot.

Here is my build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    def jettyVersion = "9.4.34.v20201102"

    implementation "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:$jettyVersion"
    implementation "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:$jettyVersion"
    implementation "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:$jettyVersion"
    implementation "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:$jettyVersion"
    implementation "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:$jettyVersion"
    implementation "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:$jettyVersion"
}
```

Here is my main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        MBeanContainer mbContainer = new MBeanContainer(getPlatformMBeanServer());
        server.addBean(mbContainer);

        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/");

        webapp.setWar(warFile()); // LOGIC TO UPLOAD WAR FILE
        webapp.setExtractWAR(true);

        Configuration.ClassList classList = Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
        classList.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
                "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");

        webapp.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
                ".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/[^/]*taglibs.*\\.jar$");

        server.setHandler(webapp);
        server.start();
        server.dumpStdErr();
        server.join();
    }
```

However, when I try to go to the app (http://localhost:8080/index), I keep getting the following error message:

```
URI:    /index
STATUS: 500
MESSAGE:    JSP support not configured
SERVLET:    jsp
```

There is only one line of error message in the console:

```
2020-12-11 09:49:51.563:INFO:oejshC.ROOT:qtp2025864991-33: No JSP support.  Check that JSP jars are in lib/jsp and that the JSP option has been specified to start.jar
```

What JSP Jars that it is referring to? I am at a loss as to what dependencies I need to add to make it work for JSPs.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add apache-jsp so that your server will support jsps. If your web app uses jstl, you should also add apache-jstl.

Comment: This is an incomplete answer, the artifact alone will only give you the classes, there's still tons of setup/initialization/configuration in the embedded-jetty code to have success with JSP on embedded-jetty.

Comment: The OP has mentioned that it is not about embedded jetty, but a separate jetty server app. Also, the OP has set the configuration (webapp.setAttribute) to include the servlet-api and servlet-api jars, but does not have them on his classpath. This might not completely fix the problem, but gives a good starting place.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen. Adding the two dependencies `org.eclipse.jetty:apache-jsp` and `org.eclipse.jetty:apache-jstl`, my app is working as expected now. I can view the page, and do not have any error message.

Comment: That shouldn't have worked with the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern` you have in your question.  The internal ServletContextInitializer would not have been found and loaded properly.  I bet you have a semi functional environment right now.  Deceptively working for your limited test cases.

Comment: It is working as expected for my web app without adding any other dependencies or configurations. This one has only one class with the main method, the war I upload uses spring's WebApplicationInitializer (it is not springboot). Your answer does have more information than simply adding the dependencies, but they are not applicable in my case. Once again, thank you for your help, and you have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

For `WebAppContext` usage (which is a bit easier to setup than `ServletContextHandler` usage) you'll need the following artifacts ...

- https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/apache-jsp (for the Jetty specific `JettyJspServlet` which extends from the Jasper `JspServlet`)
- https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/apache-jstl (to support Taglibs custom and standard)

Make sure your `org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern` can reference the apache-jsp artifact properly, otherwise the internal `javax.servlet.ServletContextInitializer` will not load properly.

If nothing happens by simply adding those artifacts, you'll need to verify your default descriptor setup on your `WebAppContext.setDefaultsDescriptor(String)` to ensure that you pass in a resource reference (path or uri) to the Jetty default descriptor XML.

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.35.v20201120/jetty-webapp/src/main/config/etc/webdefault.xml

Enabling JSP support in embedded mode can be quite tricky if you use the `ServletContextHandler` instead of the `WebAppContext`.

If you ever decide to use the `ServletContextHandler` instead of a `WebAppContext` (to have a single fat/uber jar, to speed up load/deploy time, to ease unit testing, etc...), then check out the Jetty maintained example project at ...

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp